# BottomNavigationView clear selection

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I want to clear selection of the BottomNavigationView, so no item would be selected.

I have a helper utility method:

```
public static void clearSelection(BottomNavigationView view) {
    final BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
        item.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

This kind of works, but does not reset color of the item to unchecked one (only removes raised animation and normalizes font size).

To set BottomVanigationItemView color I use color selector that sets color based on checked state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />

    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryLightTransparent" />
</selector>
```

I've tried:

```
item.invalidate();
menuView.invalidate();
```

That did not work.
How can I force views to reset color values based on the color selector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved by making all MenuItems non checkable and then making them checkable again onNavigationItemSelected.

```
public static void setCheckable(BottomNavigationView view, boolean checkable) {
    final Menu menu = view.getMenu();
    for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        menu.getItem(i).setCheckable(checkable);
    }
}
```

Comment: >> Isn't it easier to just set isChecked = false on all menu items in the for loop? << Ok it doesn't work like setChecked :)